# Is there any method to using seperate scrapy pipeline for each spider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanna to fetch web pages under different domain, that means I have to use different spider under the command "scrapy crawl myspider". However, I have to use different pipeline logic to put the data into database since the content of web pages are different. But for every spider, they have to go through all of the pipelines which defined in settings.py. Is there have other  elegant method to using seperate pipelines for each spider?

Comment: Scrapy itself does not limit a spider to a single domain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ITEM_PIPELINES` setting is defined globally for all spiders in the project during the engine start. It cannot be changed per spider on the fly.

Here are some options to consider:

- Change the code of pipelines. Skip/continue processing items returned by spiders in the `process_item` method of your pipeline, e.g.:

  ```
  def process_item(self, item, spider): 
      if spider.name not in ['spider1', 'spider2']: 
          return item  

      # process item
  ```
- Change the way you start crawling. Do it [from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), based on spider name passed as a parameter, override your `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting before calling `crawler.configure()`.

See also:

- [Scrapy. How to change spider settings after start crawling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543997/scrapy-how-to-change-spider-settings-after-start-crawling)
- [Can I use spider-specific settings?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/Uzj519saPXQ/u_lOaIh6LcsJ)
- [Using one Scrapy spider for several websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396529/using-one-scrapy-spider-for-several-websites)
- [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6502863/771848)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly better version of the above is as follows. It is better because this way allows you to selectively turn on pipelines for different spiders more easily than the coding of 'not in ['spider1','spider2']' *in the pipeline* above.

In your spider class, add:

```
#start_urls=...
pipelines = ['pipeline1', 'pipeline2'] #allows you to selectively turn on pipelines within spiders
#...
```

Then in each pipeline, you can use the `getattr` method as magic. Add:

```
class pipeline1():  
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       if 'pipeline1' not in getattr(spider, 'pipelines'):
          return item
       #...keep going as normal
```

Answer (score 2):

A more robust solution; Can't remember where I found it but a scrapy dev proposed it somewhere.. Using this method allows you to have some pipeline run on all spiders by not using the wrapper. It also makes it so you don't have to duplicate the logic of checking whether or not to use the pipeline.

Wrapper:

```
def check_spider_pipeline(process_item_method):
    """
        This wrapper makes it so pipelines can be turned on and off at a spider level.
    """
    @functools.wraps(process_item_method)
    def wrapper(self, item, spider):
        if self.__class__ in spider.pipeline:
            return process_item_method(self, item, spider)
        else:
            return item

    return wrapper
```

Usage:

```
@check_spider_pipeline
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ........
    ........
    return item
```

Spider usage:

```
pipeline = {some.pipeline, some.other.pipeline .....}
```

Comment: Hi, may you give an example ?  Is this solution need to be run from command line ?